# The reason that you might want two or more instances for same DB connection?

Tags: database, singleton

I am trying to think of a scenario that you need more than one instances of DB connection.

Normally, DB connection is one singleton object used for everything. But what's the reason that you might want to create another instance of the same class. (I read it somewhere.)

Trying to understand this, two instances of DB connections would seem very risky to cause conflict when writing to DB. But would be faster when reading? (maybe this is one reason?)

Maybe DB connection is not a very good example. You can give me other scenario if you know anywhere creating more than one instance of a Singleton class make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to be more specific on local app/embedded DB vs Servers.

But, if you have a application server (IIS, Apache etc...) that talks to a database server (SQL Server, Oracle etc...), you would want concurrency and multiple connections active at a time.  You want concurrency since it's a server handling many concurrent requests and sql servers should be able to handle that.  Serializing all database activity on a server would be catastrophic.

Concerning DB connections, with most db access technologies, they offer [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx).  So you simply open the connection, do your work and then close.  That acquires and releases the connections back into a pool so they don't have to be recreated.

Re: "Two instances of DB connections would seem very risky to cause conflict when writing to DB"

Most database servers also offer control when dealing with concurrency.  For example with sql server, you have [locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213037%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [isolation levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213034%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I am thinking from web programming point of view. I am a bit confused. I never thought about concurrency issue actually. Are you saying that if I use Singleton which creates one single object for DB connection, this would make DB connection non-concurrent? Concurrent connections is relying how many instances of the DB connections object I created in the program? I thought application server wouldn't care..

Comment: Why use a singleton?  Create a connection, do your work, close the connection.  If you have a pool your fine.  If your DB layer has the appropriate locking and isolation levels, your fine.  And you're scalable.  don't throw an artificial bottleneck in front of that.

Comment: To try to clear my confusion (I might be wrong), if a client is accessing DB, the DB connection object is created and it would be used by this client all the time. This is Singleton. But if ten clients are accesing DB, there would be ten Singleton objects created for each client. I think Singleton in the programing sense is per client per instance. So Singleton is to control the connection for one client so not to be abused with too many connections.

Comment: A singleton means only one instance (object) of that class exists in a process.  Also, a connection pool does not mean that a single client (request if server) uses the same db connection.  Read the link I had for connection pooling.  In a web server, an end user (client) makes a request, that request executes on a app server thread that creates a connection (pulled from pool under covers), does it's work, renders the page and then closes the connection releasing to the pool.  When the client makes another request, he will not get same connection.

Comment: All of this is also highly dependent on your app server and sql server technologies but the pattern is largely the same.

Comment: If it's bad programming, abusively creating many many DB connections, which would take over all the connections in the pool by one client request, this might hurt the server performance I suppose. But I see your point. Having one single object for db connection object is not as good as having many working concurrently, but not too many or it's just too complex.

Comment: Right - it's mostly about the overhead and time it takes to establish a connection.  Don't throw away that work - after the short lived (hopefully :) work is done, return it to the pool so the web server doesn't have to do that work.  A good pool will grow and shrink as load grows and shrinks with the goal of creating as few as possible while avoiding creating and destroying connections too often.

Answer (score 0):

A DB connection *pool* may be a singleton, but of course you would want to have more than one DB connection available at the same time for some applications. Think of a web server. Why wouldn't you want to be able to process concurrent requests by multiple users? And databases are usually quite good at making sure this does not cause any tragic conflicts (there is transaction isolation).